# MySQL SELECT WHERE php array equivalent

Tags: php

I am wanting to know if there is such a thing like the MySQL SELECT WHERE but in arrays.

I have this array:

```
$array = array( 1 => array('test' => '1',   'test2' => '2'  ),
                 2 => array('test' => '4','test2' => '2'
               )

);
```

I am basically wanting all the records where 'test2' = '2'. So my result should be the id's 1,2.

Can this be done?

Comment: You can loop through your array using a foreach() loop, and test the values yourself. Give it a go!

Comment: People voting to close as 'too localized'? Maybe we should have the option 'I didn't put an effort into trying to understand the question so let's close it'?

Comment: oh its a php question not a mysql one, well silly me.

Comment: Im new to Stak Overflow, give me a break... I have it originally with a foreach loop but i was just wondering if there was a different way.

Comment: asking questions that make sense is not limited to S.O; its a skill useful in all aspects of life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
array_filter($array, function ($v) { return $v["test2"] === "2"; });
```

Comment: Nota that the syntax with anonymous function will only work in PHP 5.3+. For earlier versions you need to create the callback function beforehand.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer, just wondering why did you use 3 '=' symbols?

Comment: @Marases `===` is identical; `==` is equals; See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: It's called the identity operator, and it checks if the value *and* the type of the two operands are the same. For example `"2" === "2"` is true, but `"2" === 2` is false.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [sql4array](http://absynthe.is.free.fr/sql4array/) class that allows you to use SQL to retrieve data from a PHP array, although I've never used it and can't comment on how good it is. The developers do acknowledge that it is slow though, and doesn't support the entirety of SQL syntax.

There is also [PHPLinq](http://phplinq.codeplex.com/) or alternatives that use Language Integrated Query such as [plinq](http://plinq.codeplex.com/) and [linqforphp](http://linqforphp.codeplex.com/).

Personally, I'd be inclined to use [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)